# Get port number for service name?

Tags: java

I need something like the C function [getservbyname()](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_getservbyname.htm) for a Java application. I've got to parse a configuration file that might contain either a port number or the service name, and in the latter case, I need to convert this to a port number to pass on to a library. I found [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4071389) and was a bit astonished that the question was asked in 1997 (!) and not even considered for implementation for 13 years. I don't really want to do the platform-specific parsing stuff for myself - is there any other way?

Comment: Nice. A drive-by down vote without any comment. Very helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393012/port-to-service-name-in-java) I found a library [here](http://github.com/wmeissner/jnr-netdb) which seems to do its best to provide thid functionality cross platform.

Comment: Thanks for the hint....
Unfortunately, that's a LGPL-licensed library which makes it rather hard to use in my EPL project. And it uses Maven and pulls in jruby and another strange dependency (jaffl) whose seemingly official website http://kenai.com/projects/jaffl/ tells me that the project does not exist..

Answer (score 3):

[Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/) provide some JNI binding for that:

```
package so3645405;

import org.apache.tomcat.jni.Address;
import org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library;
import org.apache.tomcat.jni.Sockaddr;
import org.apache.tomcat.jni.Socket;

public final class Net {
    private Net() {

    }

    public static int getServByName(final String serviceName) {
        try {
            Library.initialize("tcnative-1");
            long sa = Address.info(Address.APR_ANYADDR, Socket.APR_INET, 0, 0,
                    Library.globalPool());
            Sockaddr addr = new Sockaddr();
            Address.getservbyname(sa, serviceName);
            Address.fill(addr, sa);
            return addr.port;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            System.out.println(Net.getServByName(args[0]));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Usage: prog <serviceName>");
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
java -Djava.library.path=./ -classpath tomcat-coyote.jar;tomcat-juli.jar;.
      so3645405.Net https
```

Output:

```
443
```

Dependencies:

- Build time: tomcat-coyote.jar
- Runtime: tomcat-coyote.jar, tomcat-july.jar, tcnative-1 native lib.

*Tested under win64*

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but this is not a Tomcat-based application.

Answer (score 2):

Most new features added to Java have had a proven use case as an open source Java library for some time.  e.g. the concurrency library was only added after it was a stand alone library for 6 years.  Closures are only being added because most other dynamic language have it now. (And very reluctantly)

I do agree that you would think this function is available in Java except, I would also so I think very few people use it.

Comment: The way I see it, allowing for TCP networking without the resolution of service names to port numbers is like allowing file system access without caring about directories....

Comment: @vwegert - most code refers to services using hard-wires or configured port *numbers* not port names; e.g. a Java http client stack typically has the default 80 and 433 port numbers built into the code.  You'll probably even find this in C / C++ code.

Comment: @Stephen C: ...and for ports below 1024 that's a valid option to take. In this case (SAP message server port), the port number is dependent on some other parameter (the system number). Usually, the port is set as sapms<SID>, where <SID> is the three-letter system ID. So if I've got a system with the ID XYZ and the system number 42, the service sapmsXYZ will point to port 3642 - and I'd like to be able to look that up...

Comment: When was the last time you saw a service name in a web address?  Most companies keep a seperation between the OS and the applications running on that system.  As such /etc/services is part of the OS, not the application and shouldn't contain application specific configuration.  You want all you configuration in one place to simplify deployment. Embedding application specific configuration into your OS is a deployment and maintainence nightmare.

Comment: @vmegert, personally, I prefer to use configuration files.  For a shared port configuration you want to be able to manage this centrally. (NIS will do this but has its own headaches) If you want to be able to look this up dynamically I would suggest an LDAP service, however I find properties files work just fine.  Properties files also have the advantage that they can contain any kind of configuration information, allowing you to keep all your configuration for a component together. How do you version your services file, or distribute updates?

Comment: @Peter: Just to clarify this, I have no control over either the format of the configuration file or the way I have to pass the port number on. If the config file contains the service name, then I'll have to parse it, whether I like it or not. Whether you think it's a nightmare or not won't affect the format of the configuration file either...

Comment: @vweget, in other words, you have to support service names, and whether its a good idea is not within your control.  My comments were more for people who thought service names were the only sensible solution to mapping services to ports and I would say there is good reasons why most people don't use them.